# Node/Express promise doesn't get re-called on subsequent route requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, promise

### The Problem

I've got a route (`/mediumData`) that gets called on every page reload of a website. Here is the express router handler for the route:

```
router.get("/mediumData", (request, response) => {
    getMediumData
        .then(mediumData => {
            response.json(mediumData)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            response.send(error)
        })
});
```

The issue I'm running into is that the promise `getMediumData` **only gets called when the server restarts, and not on every page load like intended**.

### What I've Tried

When I've tried debugging the code with `console.log` statements, I found out that the `console.log` was being executed inside of the `getMediumData.then` handler (on page refreshes). However, the `getMediumData` promise would not execute any `console.log` statements on page refreshes (only on server restarts would the `console.log` be executed).

Here is an example of what I'm talking about regarding my `console.log` debugging:

**`getMediumData.then` handler**

```
router.get("/mediumData", (request, response) => {
    getMediumData
        .then(mediumData => {
            console.log("This text gets outputted on every page refresh.");
            response.json(mediumData)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            response.send(error)
        })
});
```

**`getMediumData` promise**

```
const getMediumData = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("This text only gets outputted on server restarts.");
    https
        .get(
            // Some stuff...
        )
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promises can only be resolved/rejected once, it's just how they work. So a simple solution here would be to wrap your existing `getMediumData` promise in a function that creates a new promise for every request.

For example:

```js
const getMediumData = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  https
    .get(
      // Some stuff...
    )
});

router.get("/mediumData", (request, response) => {
  getMediumData().then(mediumData => {
    response.json(mediumData)
  }).catch(error => {
    response.send(error)
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your clean answer with useable code! Super useful and it solved my issue 

Comment: @RobertCooper Glad it helped! 

Answer (score 1):

The code wrapped by the `getMediumData` promise executes only once. To execute it in every request, you could move the assignment (i.e. `getMediumData = new Promise(...)` into the body of the route.

Alternatively, you can wrap the promise creation logic into a function returning a new promise each time and use that function in the route.

```
const getMediumDataPromise = () => new Promise(
  (resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("This text only gets outputted on server restarts.");
    https
        .get(
            // Some stuff...
        )
  }
);

router.get("/mediumData", (request, response) => {
    getMediumDataPromise()
        .then(mediumData => {
            console.log("This text gets outputted on every page refresh.");
            response.json(mediumData)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            response.send(error)
        })
});
```